# One of the dependencies (ofbcore:ofbcore-xerces:jar:serializer) is nowhere to be found in the internet

Tags: maven, jar, jira, jira-plugin

I am trying to create a .jar file out of this [project](https://github.com/ideotech/tinymce-renderer-plugin). It is a plugin for Jira. To do so, I am using [Altassian SDK](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/set-up-the-atlassian-plugin-sdk-and-build-a-project/install-the-atlassian-sdk-on-a-windows-system). Everything goes well but maven couldn't resolve one of the dependencies. It gives me following error,

```
Downloading: http://www.doveltech.com/maven/ofbcore/ofbcore-xerces/serializer/ofbcore-xerces-serializer.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ofbcore/ofbcore-xerces/serializer/ofbcore-xerces-serializer.pom
[WARNING] The POM for ofbcore:ofbcore-xerces:jar:serializer is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/ofbcore/ofbcore-xerces/serializer/ofbcore-xerces-serializer.jar
Downloading: file://C:\Applications\Atlassian\atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.9/repository/ofbcore/ofbcore-xerces/serializer/ofbcore-xerces-serializer.jar
Downloading: http://www.doveltech.com/maven/ofbcore/ofbcore-xerces/serializer/ofbcore-xerces-serializer.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ofbcore/ofbcore-xerces/serializer/ofbcore-xerces-serializer.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.518 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-03T19:40:42-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/334M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project tinymce-renderer-plugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ideotechnologies.jira:tinymce-renderer-plugin:atlassian-plugin:1.7.1: Could not find artifact ofbcore:ofbcore-xerces:jar:serializer in atlassian-public (https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public) -> [Help 1]
```

Here, as the error says, maven couldn't resolve that particular .jar file in the public repo. I later added the repo, http://www.doveltech.com/maven/ as someone claimed it fixed his similar issue. But, apparently, that url is empty directory. I looked for alternative urls but in vain.

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced same error sometime back, the following worked

1) Clean everything in /.m2 
2) `mvn compile` 
3) `mvn install`

I believe `mvn compile` builds all the necessary jars that resolve "Could not resolve dependencies" errors.

Further,
You can also check if your **setting.xml** file is in the right location. 
`vim settings.xml` gives you this information

This is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two levels:

1. **User Level**. This **settings.xml** file provides configuration for a single user, and is normally provided in `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`.

   ```
   NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
   -s /path/to/user/settings.xml
   ```
2. **Global Level**. This **settings.xml** file provides configuration for all Maven users on a machine (assuming they're all using the same Maven installation). It's normally provided in `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`.

   ```
   NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
   -gs /path/to/global/settings.xml
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Atlassian Repository

```
<repository>
      <id>atlassian-public</id>
      <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
       <releases>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
</repository>
```

Comment: just tried this. Still gives same error. Checking the url, I did find ofbcore folder but not the subfolder ofbcore-xerces that maven is looking for..